# How do i insert one table and update another table in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two tables, purchase with four fields (id,supplier,items,and quantity), and i have items table with four fields(id,items_name,quantity). When ever i insert data in purchase table, i want to update the quantity of that item in items table. For example if i purchase one item, the quantity will be updated in items table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [overriding](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) save method of `purchase` class.

If `items` field in `purchase` class is foreign key to `items` class, it could look like this.

```
class purchase(models.Model):

    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.items.quantity = *value you need*
        self.items.save()
```

Comment: yes it is foreign key, can i change the
self.items.quantity=self.items.quantity+quantity(this one from form field) ?

Comment: I guess you want this `self.items.quantity = self.items.quantity + self.quantity` or to make it in pythonic way `self.items.quantity += self.quantity`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/). That way you do not need to override the save method. And just react to that event (in our case the `post_save` signal)

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Purchase)
def update_quantity(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # If its a foreign key:
    for item in instance.items.all(): 
        item.quantity = ... 
        item.save()
```